# Scratching Audio

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, audio

I was wondering where to start if I want to implement scratching features in my app. The user selects a sound file, and can see a LP spinning. I want the user to be able to scratch the song like a DJ.

Who can tell me where to start? Or has some example or something?

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,

Kenneth

Comment: Software like this makes me want to cry.  :-D  I think Mix Master Mike dies a little when he sees those damn iPad commercials...

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.xwax.co.uk/ for some open source vinyl emulation software.

Comment: Hi, this is no library for the iPhone/iPad. I know you want to point me to the right direction but do you know any libraries for the iPhone/iPad? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK xwax is written in C. Yes, you will have replace the UI, audio IO and decoding parts with cocoa/iOS equivalents but the DSP for scratching audio should be able to be used as is.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can't find the DSP you are talking about in the project. And can you use it with MPMusicPlayerController? Thanks

Comment: @CyberK - I'm not familiar with the xwax code - but I know from using the software (and others like it) that it is capable of "scratching" as you describe, so I think it would be a good piece of software to study.  I don't think you'll be able to use MPMusicPlayerController, you will need to use lower latency [Audio Units](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)